# How to limit a custom property to available values in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, enums

I have an enum declared as follows:

```
public enum DirectionTypes
{
    IN = 2,
    OUT = 1
}
```

This enum is used on user controls where I need to specify in XAML which direction the control needs to work.  I created a dependency property on each user control as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectionTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
           "DirectionType",
           typeof(DirectionTypes),
           typeof(TransactionGrid), new PropertyMetadata(DirectionTypes.IN));

public DirectionTypes DirectionType
{
    get
    {
        return (DirectionTypes)GetValue(DirectionTypeProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(DirectionTypeProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I can then use the user control as follows:

```
<local:TransactionGrid x:Name="theGrid" DirectionType="OUT" />
```

I can run the program just fine.  The problem is that **DirectionType="OUT"** causes an intellisense error in Visual Studio 2015.  I get blue squiglies under the XAML property and my designer won't show the preview, saying instead "Invalid Markup".  The error says **The Type converter for DirectionTypes does not support converting from a string.**

What am I missing that will allow the XAML parse properly.

Comment: That's just the broken XAML Designer. Try to rebuild your solution, or close and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: This has been an issue that has persisted for weeks (multiple re-builds, clean solutions, etc....).  I only care about it now because I am making changes to the control and the designer isn't giving me a preview of the control, which is annoying me to no end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the enumeration value explicitly as follows (assuming DirectionTypes is in the same name space as local):

```
<local:TransactionGrid x:Name="theGrid" DirectionType="{x:Static local:DirectionTypes.OUT}" />
```

Comment: This works, but I was hoping for a solution similar to how you do background colors...where I would simply use "IN" or "OUT" and intellisense would only give you those two strings as available options.  If there isn't an answer that can explain how to do that, I'll go ahead and mark this as the solution in a couple days.